# miss the time to go to bed

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-choice

> Typically people tell themselves that they should go to bed at 11 or
> 12, but often they watch TV series and ...

I want to say people watch TV series for too long, and missed the time to go to bed (at 11 or 12), and when they realize they shoud sleep, it's already 2 am.

So how do I express this in a concise and idiomatic way?

> ... but often they watch TV series and **miss the time**?

or

> ... **miss the deadline**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common way would be to say that they **missed their bedtime** (at least in American English).

Answer (score 1):

"... and stay up later than they intended", or just "...stay up later."

Comment: I don't know about the Brits, but Americans commonly say "I stayed up past my bedtime."

Comment: Yes, we say that here too. Of course, adults don't normally have a formal 'deadline' that they can 'miss', just their usual approximate bedtime.

Comment: Sometimes we just say "I stayed up late".